# How to install and use numpy python package in docker container

Tags: python, numpy, docker

I'm building a docker image that suppose to run a python script that depends on some packages (numpy) I install during the build.
During build everything appears to be installed correctly but when I run the container it behaves like those packages were never installed. What seems to be the problem with my code ?

My docker file looks like this :

```
FROM myimage as intermediate

WORKDIR ./app

COPY ./mathServer ./mathServer/

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install sudo 

RUN sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y

RUN sudo pip3 install numpy 

RUN sudo pip3 install httpserver 

RUN pip3 list

WORKDIR ./app

COPY --from=intermediate ./app/* ./

CMD ["sh","-c","python3 mathServer/mathServer.py"]
```

I would expect docker run myimage to run mathServer.py successfully but instead it complains about numpy package.
"importError: No module named 'numpy''"
Also if I replace command "python3 mathServer/mathServer.py" with command "pip3 list" pip3 command does not exist. Somehow the packages installed during build are not available when I'm actually running the container.

Comment: [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploying-scipy-numpy-with-docker-205e9afac3b0) may helps

Answer (score 1):

Please check your docker build log. `Numpy` requests c compiler and fortran compiler to build and install.  It is likely the installation was not successful.

Consider try pre-build dockers such as https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/miniconda/, and add `numpy` via `RUN <PATH_TO>/conda install numpy -y`

Or https://hub.docker.com/r/continuumio/anaconda3 that already have `numpy`installed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Installation appears to be fine along with other packages there is no error during build. Here is the result of the installed packages pip3 list :
httpserver (1.1.0)
keyrings.alt (1.3)
numpy (1.17.2)
pip (9.0.1)
However "pip3 list" does not work when I'm runing the container with CMD [..]. I think this is the same reason why numpy isn't visible either.

Comment: So it was a mistake in my docker file , the instructions I had at the end
WORKDIR ./app
COPY --from=intermediate ./app/* ./
override the numpy instalation
So you were right :) by the time I was running the container numpy was not installed

Comment: ha that's easy, nonetheless, the conda/miniconda based dockers are worth trying.  More consistent at least.